# Why isn't my CSS changing here as it should be?

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following HTML in conjunction with some PHP:

```
echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?guess=" . $value . "' class='already-guessed'>" . $value . "</a>\n";
```

It applies a special class if it's been already guessed, as the class implies. I have this if it hasn't been guessed:

```
echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?guess=" . $value . "'>" . $value . "</a>\n";
```

And this is the relevant CSS:

```
.letters a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 3px 6px 0;

    background: #5ac9ff;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    .letters a:nth-child(10n) {
        margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    }

    .letters a:hover {
        background: #54bff3;
    }

    .letters a:active {
        background: #4fb4e4;
    }

.already-guessed {
    background: green;
}
```

So I just have it detect all anchor.

Comment: Can you show the final HTML instead of the PHP source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector for the anchor gives precedence. Change your code for the `.already-guessed` class as follows:

```
.already-guessed {
    background: green !important;
}
```

Or, if you'd prefer, update the selector:

```
.letters a.already-guessed {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: lol, I was already editing. I don't think `!important` is as bad as it's made out to be honest.

Comment: not in this simple context, no, but it can become a pain in the arse quickly. (I speak from experience)